# Queue module error

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import threading 
import Queue
import time 
from ftplib import FTP


ftphostlist = ['ftp.x.org', 'ftp4.FreeBSD.org', 'ftp.ncsa.uiuc.edu',
'ftp.crans.org']

class WorkerThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, queue, tid):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.queue = queue
        self.tid = tid
        print "Worker %d Reporting for Service Sir!" % self.tid

    def run(self):

        while True: 
            host = None


            try: 
                host = self.queue.get(timeout=1)

                #time.sleep(2)


            except Queue.Empty: 
                print "Worker %d exiting..." % self.tid
                return


            #login to ftp host anonymously and list the dirs 
            self.lock.acquire()
            try: 
                conn = FTP(host)
                conn.login()
                print 'Host: ' + host
                time.sleep(2)
                print host + conn.retrlines('LIST')



            except: 
                print "Error in listing" +host
                raise
                self.lock.release()

            self.queue.task_done()

queue = Queue.Queue()

threads = []
for i in range(1, 5): 
    t = threading.Thread(target=WorkerThread, args=('Threads -1', 3))
    t.start()
    print "Creating WorkerThread : %d" %i 
    worker = WorkerThread(queue, i)
    worker.setDaemon(True)
    worker.start()
    threads.append(worker)
    print "WorkerThread %d Created!" %i 
    time.sleep(.2)

for host in ftphostlist: 
    queue.put(host)

queue.join()

#wait for all the threads to exit

for item in threads: 
    item.join

print "Scanning Complete!"
```

Hi,

I am very new to python and was trying to make an FTP connecter as suggested by Pentesteracademy. I was working on an exercise which seemed to run correctly for a few times and then i get an error stating

```
"File "ftp_login.py", line 4, in <module>
    from Queue import *
  File "/media/sf_Python/Pentest/Queue.py", line 22, in <module>
    queue = Queue.Queue()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"
```

I am not sure exactly where i went wrong but I have spent quite a few useless hours trying to figure it out. Sorry if the issue is simple I am just failing to see it

Comment: Is this Python 3? Do `python --version`

Comment: did you create file `Queue.py` ? Now `import Queue` try to import your file `Queue.py` instead of standard Python module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your local module has name `Queue` and it is being imported instead of the original queue:

```
File "ftp_login.py", line 4, in <module>
    from Queue import *
  File "/media/sf_Python/Pentest/Queue.py", line 22, in <module>
      ~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^~
```

Just rename your `/media/sf_Python/Pentest/Queue.py` file

Comment: Thank You very much. This is precisely what the issue was. The issue started right after i saved a  file with the name queue.py. I failed to take that into account. It is crystal clear now. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

Module object is not callable could be due to wrong import/usage.

The correct way is:

```
# python2
from Queue import Queue
q = Queue()

# python3
from queue import Queue
q = Queue()
```

or

```
# python2
import Queue
q = Queue.Queue()

# python3
import queue
q = queue.Queue()
```